# Dynamic manifest values for chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

I have a chrome extension I've developed and I want to have some sort of an ID for each user.

Ideally I would place this ID in the manifest, and call it via `chrome.app.getDetails().userid`

Then I can use this id to get a feed every X hours and the feed is different for each `userid`.

If I serve the CRX file myself, I can do this by simply writing a quick PHP script that changes the manifest upon download request and inserts the id using a certain logic while also inserting the same id to a mysql table.

How can I do this while serving the extension through the Chrome Web Store?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not include user-specific values in the manifest file. A better approach is by using the extension's persistence.

One logical place to define such an id is the [options page](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/options.html).
Another possible option is a background script, which follows the following logic:

```
    var userid = localStorage.getItem('userid');
    if (!userid) {
        // Create new useruid, either via a server-side script, or client-side
        // ...
        localStorage.setItem('userid', 'new user id');
    }
```

In this example, I used `localStorage` to enable persistence. You can also use the [`chrome.storage`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/storage.html)<sup>Chrome 20+</sup> instead, which allows users to synchronise their profiles and settings.

Instead of checking and retrieving the id at the first run, you can also implement the logic at the server's side. For instance, let's assume that the server's response format is JSON. Then, simply define the uid in the response (optionally, only if it's changed):

```
var userid = localStorage.getItem('userid');
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'http://example.com/feeds/json?userid=' + userid);
xhr.onload = function() {
    var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
    if (response.userid) { // Set new uid if needed
        localStorage.setItem('userid', userid = response.userid);
    }
    // ... your application's logic ...
};
xhr.send();
```

The server has to implement the following:

1. If the request (query string?) contains a `userid` key, check whether the userid is valid and known.

   - If the `userid` is invalid, generate one, and include it in the response.
2. *Your application's logic here*

Which causes the response to look like (To generate JSON using PHP, use [`json_encode`](http://php.net/json_encode)):

```
{"userid":"some unique user identifier", ....}
```

Comment: One more question.. Currently the logic works in a way where the user makes a request to download the extension with a predefined user id value, then I have the php script that edits the manifest file on the drive, creates the CRX and serves to the user. What you wrote above is great and I should change the location of where I save the user id, but I'm still unsure of how I can get a var value (user id in this example) from the URL request to anywhere in the CRX of a specific user when he downloads it - whether i'm using the chrome storage feature or the manifest way..

Comment: @user838437 In my proposed solution, the id is *not* included in the extension (CRX file). It is generated and set when the user uses the extension for the first time. The flow: 1.Client: Request CRX, 2.Server: Offers static CRX file 3.Client: Installs CRX file 4.Client (First run): Request feed, included a void userid. 5.Server: Can't find a valid userid, responds new userid and feed. 6.Client: Remember userid. *Later: The client checks for new feeds:* A.Client: Send userid 3.Server:Recognises userid, send user-specific feed response.

Comment: OK, but in case I want to have a predefined user id, how can I approach this?

Comment: @user838437 Not, the Chrome Web Store does not offer that level of flexibility.