# How to save user information in a chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Im making a chrome extension. I need the user to be assigned a unique id they get from my web site. how do i save this information in my chrome extension so that each time the browser is started the extension has the same unique id?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamic manifest values for chrome extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11521909/dynamic-manifest-values-for-chrome-extension)

Answer (score 1):

Use [local storage](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage.html), it's persistent across sessions.